# Is crypto an uncorrelated (or negatively correlated to traditional markets) asset class?

Tags: stocks, cryptocurrency, hedging

In preparation for an upcoming financial crisis, for instance, something of the magnitude of the 2008's capital C crisis, would crypto (given their current market size and state) be (part of) a good hedge against the established asset classes(stocks/bonds/ETFs etc)?

Comment: I guess something you can ask yourself in pondering this question, is: if cryptocurrency is negatively correlated with traditional asset classes, then was the ~30% drop in crypto value over the last 7 days in conjunction with a ~25% increase  in any type of traditional asset class? .... [no - there was no such correlation].

Comment: Some would question whether cryptocurrency is an asset at all.

Comment: Bounty added. Lets see how this goes.

Comment: @BrenBarn If it can give you money, it's an asset.

Comment: @Grade'Eh'Bacon Correlation doesn't mean that they always move together.

Comment: Could you please not abuse the word "crypto" when you mean crypto currency? "Crypto" is what keeps your computer safe. "Crypto currency" is what empties your wallet.

Comment: @gnasher729 I would say the title mentioning asset classes and the full text being present in the tags where brevity isn't an issue should be enough to make the distinction obvious, pet peeves aside that is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Investing involves an evaluation of risk in return for an expected amount of reward.

At  one end  you have speculation where an investor takes on a large amount of risk with an expectation that the potential profit is  worth the large potential loss.  At the other end you have safe investments like bonds  with an almost guaranteed return.  Across the spectrum you have stocks (common, preferred, convertibles), options, and  funds (mutual, closed, ETFs).

I'd  guess that while most investors know the terms (Bitcoin, Ethereum, crypto), like me, they don't know much more about crypto than that.  I'd also guess that adherents believe that crypto  will take care of  everything from a market crash to acne.  AFAIC, it's a highly speculative gamble.

In bear markets, there's a flight to safety, at least for those who do not want to ride their portfolio down 50+ percent (see 2000 and 2008).  For those who don't get out but want to lower exposure, more speculative stocks are sold off and lower beta defensive positions are taken.

I can't imagine that any traditional investor would consider crypto to be in  the 'flight to safety' category so I really doubt that crypto will soar for that reason.  It could do well (another round of speculative buying) but IMO,  a GFC repeat would not be causal.

If you want to hedge, consider more traditional ways which are guaranteed to limit the Carnage if there is another  capital C financial Crisis.

Comment: s/traditional/sane/.  Cryptocurrency is the opposite of "safe", as the last week or so will show.

Comment: First of thanks for the helpful and informative answer. I know that the crypto market is highly speculative right now but I have the background to review technology while making picks and I was also considering of it as no more than a 5-10% position of the total portfolio, not going all in for the sake of hedging. 
I will add a bounty tomorrow since I think crypto related questions in this stack go no further than "where to buy this/how to buy this". Also, if you have a primer on more traditional hedging suggestions I would love to study it.

Comment: You can hedge in a variety of ways: diversification (iffy), gold (iffy), covered calls (modest protection), long puts (high cost), no/low cost option collars, short stocks and ETFs, long inverse ETFs.  Google: "Hedge stock positions" and you'll find lots of articles that explain various ways to do this.  Bear in mind that many hedging techniques involve giving up some degree of profit potential in return for limiting risk.

Answer (score 1):

> would crypto (given their current market size and state) be (part of) a good hedge against the established asset classes(stocks/bonds/ETFs etc)?

According to [this site](https://www.sifrdata.com/cryptocurrency-correlation-matrix/), crypto has an insignificant (near zero) correlation to traditional equity and bond markets. That does *not* mean that it is an effective hedge. A hedge would mean that if one moves up, the other moves down (*negative* correlation). What it means is that you can use it to diversify and have a risk (variance) that is less than the sum of the risks of the two portfolios. So you can expect higher returns with lower *relative* risk.

If you are expecting a financial crisis, then crypto may not be an effective hedge. You'd need assets that are *negatively* correlated to traditional markets (options to reduce downside risk, contra ETFs, etc.). Of course, investing in those will *reduce* returns in a bull equity market, so you'd have to be willing to accept lower returns in good times for lower losses in bad times.

Comment: What it means is that you can use it to diversify and have a risk (variance) that is less than the sum of the risks of the two portfolios. So you can expect higher returns with lower relative risk.
... vesting in those will reduce returns in a bull equity market, so you'd have to be willing to accept lower returns in good times for lower losses in bad times.

Those 2 parts are the most important take away from this answer. Thanks for the insight as well as the link, I ll study it further.

Answer (score 0):

Crypto markets are fueled entirely by psychology and perceived and expected value. It was intended to be thought of as a currency but due to shady characters they have shilled it into the minds of the misinformed to be something similar to an asset class that grows over time based on mass adoption? I'm not sure what the mechanism for its expected growth is to be. But I will tell you one thing is for sure and the SEC is involved as well as many world governments including the United States, and that certain people propped up the price illegally last year causing it to skyrocket.

The current bitcoin death spiral is a consequence of the bitcoin hash wars here is a link of an interview of one of the perpetrators:https://ambcrypto.com/bitcoin-btc-price-drop-is-not-a-goal-but-a-consequence-of-bitcoin-cash-bch-sv-mining-says-craig-wright/

[www.tradingview.com](https://www.tradingview.com) they have just about every cryptocurrency pair imaginable in the chart section. Take a look at [www.coinmarketcap.com](https://www.coinmarketcap.com) as well.

Comment: While most of what you said is valid, I dont think relevant to the question asked entirely. Feel free to make it more relevant and I ll upvote it.